# VisualForce - If(CONTAINS) assistance in user form

Tags: visualforce, contains

I'm working with 'Contains' in VisualForce and have a user-fillable form.  I want the user to be able to select an option from a picklist and then populate another pageblock section based on if the user's picklist selection contains a specific value.  Otherwise, I do not want this section to be rendered.

Can someone please explain to me why the code below does not work and assist in fixing it?

Thank you

```
<p>  
  Personal Care Concerns:
</p>

<div class="selectiondiv">
  <apex:inputField styleClass="fieldset" value="{!Intake__c.Personal_Care__c}"/>
</div>


<apex:pageblock>
    <apex:pageblockSection >
         <apex:outputText rendered="{!IF(CONTAINS(Intake__c.Personal_Care__c,"Toileting/Bathing/Self-Care in Bathroom"), "true", "false")}" value="SimplyHome System" />
    </apex:pageblockSection>
</apex:pageblock>
```

Comment: Please have a look here: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/156887/rendering-pageblocksections-based-on-picklist

Comment: This worked perfectly, Thank you!

Comment: Not sure if this will _completely_ fix your problem, but you're returning "true" and "false" strings inside your expression when that shouldn't be necessary. `CONTAINS` returns a true/false by default. You can simplify the expression to: `{!CONTAINS(Intake__c.Personal_Care__c,'Toileting/Bathing/Self-Care in Bathroom')}`

Comment: You can also take a look at the trailhead for [Dynamic Pages](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/users/strailhead/trailmixes/be-an-innovator-with-dynamic-pages). It covers a no-code approach for creating forms similar to one you're trying to implement in Visualforce.